# failed to install ruby Error running '__rvm_make -j4',

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

### Description

Unable to Install Ruby 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 15~22.04.1

### Steps to reproduce

1. Run rvm install "3.0.2"

### Expected behavior

Ruby is installed

### Actual behavior

Error running '__rvm_make -j4',

[image]

**Debug mode**:
[make.log](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/files/14076533/make.log)

### Environment info

[image]

`rvm info`

> `system:
>
> system:
> uname:        "Linux cas12-GemiBook-Pro 6.5.0-15-generic #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jan 12 18:54:30 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
> name:         "Ubuntu"
> version:      "22.04"
> architecture: "x86_64"
> bash:         "/usr/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
> zsh:          "/usr/bin/zsh => zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)"
> remote_path:  "ubuntu/22.04/x86_64"
>
> rvm:
> version:      "1.29.12 (manual)"
> updated:      "51 minutes 1 second ago"
> path:         "/usr/share/rvm"
> autolibs:     "[4] Allow RVM to use package manager if found, install missing dependencies, install package manager (only OS X)."
>
> homes:
> gem:          "not set"
> ruby:         "not set"
>
> binaries:
> ruby:         "/usr/bin/ruby"
> irb:          "/usr/bin/irb"
> gem:          "/usr/bin/gem"
> rake:         "/usr/bin/rake"
>
> environment:
> PATH:         "/home/cas12/istio-1.20.1/bin/:/root/go/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/third_party/etcd:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/root/kubectl-plugins:/home/cas12/istio-1.20.1/bin:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/lib:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/command-not-found:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/docker:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/docker-compose:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/fancy-ctrl-z:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/git-extras:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/gnu-utils:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/yarn:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/git:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/gh:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/terraform:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/aws:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/history:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/oc:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/npm:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/node:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/mvn:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/golang:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/kubectl:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/pip:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/systemd:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/python:/root/.antigen/bundles/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/plugins/tmux:/root/.antigen/bundles/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions:/root/.antigen/bundles/popstas/zsh-command-time:/root/.antigen/bundles/urbainvaes/fzf-marks:/root/.antigen/bundles/ytet5uy4/fzf-widgets:/root/.antigen/bundles/zdharma-continuum/fast-syntax-highlighting:/usr/share/rvm/bin"
> GEM_HOME:     ""
> GEM_PATH:     ""
> MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
> IRBRC:        ""
> RUBYOPT:      ""
> gemset:       ""
> `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the `make.log`, the errors are all relating to the openssl linking. This is probably because you have openssl >= 3.0 installed on your system - which ruby 3.0 didn't support. You'll need to install openssl-1.1.1, or use ruby >= 3.1

Comment: Rails 7.1.3 works only with ruby 3.0...

Comment: That's not true, Rails 7.1.3 works with any ruby >= 2.7 including >= 3.1.